# Update a field depending on other fields

Tags: formula, workflow

I have a field called 'Data Quality Score' in the contact object. This is a text field.
I have three other fields in contact ( 2 picklists and one text field).

Data Quality Score depends on these 3 fields. If all these 3 fields are blank, then the Data Quality Score should be 70.
If we add a value to one of the fields then the value becomes 70 + 10=80. each of these 3 fields accounts for a 10 score.

If all 3 fields are filled then the Data Quality Score should be 100.

Can we do this field update with workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflow is not necessary, but would work.

Simply define a formula field that returns 70 plus 10 for each non blank field.

70 + if(not(isblank(field1)),10,0) + if(not(isblank(text(picklistField))),10,0)

etc..